# oracle sql handle fixed formulas in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some Data Which is Using Formulas Like This

```
Month      Per Month  Credit  Loan_AMt    Down_PAyment    Balance
Jan-2013   5906        3555     7500000     225000      Loan_amt-downpymnt-permnth-credit
Feb-2013   5906        3555     7500000     225000      Balance - permnth - credit
Mar-2013   5906        3555     7500000     225000      Balance - permnth - credit
Apr-2013   5906        3555     7500000     225000      Balance - permnth - credit 
May-2013   5906        3555     7500000     225000      Balance - permnth - credit
```

Here the First line Balance Formula is From Loan Amount and Other all lines Use the Above Balance Like if Firs Line Return the  515,539 the Second Line Will be

```
515,539 - 5906 - 3555 =  506,078
```

and Next Will be

```
506,078 - 5906 - 3555 =  496,617
```

and So On till End
I want to Achieve this In Sql Query.Any One Plz Help !

Comment: Try using LAG() function...http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to cumulatively subtract the values from the first record. You can make use of FIRST_VALUE to get the first loan_amt and down_payment, and SUM to find the cumulative sum of credit and permnth.
Then, just subtract this cumulative sum from the first (loan_amt - down_payment).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38f18/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table myt(
    month_      date,
    per_month_  number,
    credit_     number,
    loan_amt_   number,
    down_payment_ number
    );

insert into myt values(date'2013-01-01',5906,3555,750000,225000);
insert into myt values(date'2013-02-01',5906,3555,750000,225000);
insert into myt values(date'2013-03-01',5906,3555,750000,225000);
insert into myt values(date'2013-04-01',5906,3555,750000,225000);
insert into myt values(date'2013-05-01',5906,3555,750000,225000);
```

**Query**:

```
select month_,
       per_month_,
       credit_,
       loan_amt_,
       down_payment_,
       first_value(loan_amt_ - down_payment_) over (order by month_) - 
       sum(per_month_ + credit_) over (order by month_) balance
from   myt
order by month_
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38f18/2/1)**:

```
|                          MONTH_ | PER_MONTH_ | CREDIT_ | LOAN_AMT_ | DOWN_PAYMENT_ | BALANCE |
|---------------------------------|------------|---------|-----------|---------------|---------|
|  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       5906 |    3555 |    750000 |        225000 |  515539 |
| February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       5906 |    3555 |    750000 |        225000 |  506078 |
|    March, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       5906 |    3555 |    750000 |        225000 |  496617 |
|    April, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       5906 |    3555 |    750000 |        225000 |  487156 |
|      May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       5906 |    3555 |    750000 |        225000 |  477695 |
```

Comment: Sir These are Not Required Results First Value should be `515,539` and Second `506,078` and so On as I Wrote in Question

Comment: Updated the answer. It was due to an extra zero in loan_amount column and i was adding loan_amount and down_payment, instead of subtracting.